# Should I use the definite article "the" in this sentence?

Tags: definite-articles

Which of these two sentences is grammatically correct?

"Engine in the heart, fuel in veins."
"Engine in the heart, fuel in the veins."

This is a sentence for a tattoo, which basically says, that the person loves cars.

Comment: The second version (an article in front of each) reads the most naturally to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can minimize the amount of pain you'll need to endure by not using any definite article.

My suggestion:

> Engine in Heart. Fuel in Veins

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'd also like to know if there's a difference in meaning between your version and Jason's version?

Comment: @Aschente: No, there's no difference in meaning. Jason's version may SOUND better, or have a certain "ring" to it; sometimes, however, "less is more." I mean if you really don't care how long your expression is, you may as well think about using this: "There's an engine in my heart and fuel in my veins," or 
this: "I've got an engine for a heart and fuel for blood," or this: "My heart is an engine, and my blood is fuel." I think you get the point. If you want a dozen more, I'd be glad to give 'em to you! Don

Comment: I suggest you do no such thing but if you must gone down that route,. why stretch it and use "Engine heart; fuel veins"?